# sequelize is not defined in index.js for sequelize models

Tags: node.js, model, sequelize.js

I got a model folder which contains all sequelize schema models, and I tried to write an index.js in this model folder; but when I run the app, there is an error "sequelize is not defined" in the index.js. Please see my codes below.

```js
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
const db = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}


fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === ".js");
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

sequelize
          .authenticate()
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Connection has been established succesfully");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Unable to connect to the database:", err);
          })

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.group = require('./group')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.service = require('./service')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.store = require('./store')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.appointment = require('./appointment')(sequelize, Sequelize);


module.exports = db;
```

Comment: you have declared 'sequelize' inside if block. That is why you are getting that error. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @R.Sarkar you should make that an answer

Comment: @SanSolo did that. It is a small change that is why i have posted that as comment.

Comment: @R.Sarkar, I suggested that so you could get points :)

Answer (score 2):

you have declared 'sequelize' inside if block. That is why you are getting that error. Hope this will help you.